# How do I open Multiple NotePad files from a folder? in Windows 10

Tags: windows

How do I open Multiple NotePad files from a folder?in Windows 10 Selecting all and then pressing Enter won't work, Selecting all and then trying to get an option of open by right clicking mouse button don't work.

Comment: I disagree: Selecting multiple `.txt` files, right-click and Open does open all files.

Comment: Yea I tried selecting multiple files by clicking Shift and selecting 10 files at a time, then clicked on the right mouse button it worked, it gave the option to open the files, but when I tried to open all 20 of them, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an arbitrary limit of 15 selected files in the context-menu, as
explained in this Microsoft article:
[Context menus are shortened when more than 15 files are selected](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2022295/context-menus-are-shortened-when-more-than-15-files-are-selected).

The solution is to use `regedit` and navigate to the key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`.

On the right-hand pane, change the value of the item
`MultipleInvokePromptMinimum` to a limit that suits you better.
If the item does not exist, create it as DWORD 32-bit.

The change takes place right away without a logoff or restart.
However, I would be careful with setting this to a too big value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch files to filter an open files in notepad:

```
@echo off & cd "Folder" & for %%a in (*) do notepad "%%~fa"
```